# Find ascending duplicate pairs in an array

Tags: c#, algorithm

Given an array A with zero index and N integers find equal elements with different positions in the array. Pair of indexes (P,Q) such that 0 <= P < Q < N such that A[P] = A[Q]. My algorithm is below but I am looking for a O(N*logN) solution.

```
    public int solution(int[] A)
    {
        int N = A.Length;            
        int count = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            count += FindPairs(A[j], j, A);
        }

        return count;
    }

    public int FindPairs(int item, int ci, int[] A)
    {
        int len = A.Length;
        int counter=0;
        int k = ci+1;
        while (k < len)
        {
            if (item == A[k])
                counter++;
            k++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code which belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why don't you just stick the integers into a hash table or use Enumerable.GroupBy(integers, x => x)? This problem is O(N).

Comment: The question is on-topic. It's about finding a better approach given working code that doesn't meet complexity requirements.

Answer (score 2):

From your code, it looks like the goal is to return the count of ascending duplicate pairs in `A`.

We observe that if there are `m` occurrences of the number `x` in `A`, then the number of ascending duplicate pairs of the value `x` is `m choose 2`, or `m (m - 1) / 2`.

So, we sum up `m (m - 1) / 2` for each unique `x`, giving us the answer.

In pseudocode, this looks like:

```
count = new Dictionary();
foreach a in A {
    count[a]++;
}
total = 0;
foreach key, value in count {
    total += value * (value - 1) / 2;
}
return total;
```

This algorithm is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

Recent interview question … here is what I did:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Codility
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public struct Indice
        {
            public Indice(int p, int q)
            {
                P = p;
                Q = q;
            }

            public int P;
            public int Q;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("({0}, {1})", P, Q);
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //                      0 1 2 3 4 5 
            int[] list = new int[] {3,3,3,3,3,3};

            int answer = GetPairCount(list);

            Console.WriteLine("answer = " + answer);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int GetPairCount(int[] A)
        {
            if (A.Length < 2) return 0;

            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<Indice, Indice>> tracker = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<Indice, Indice>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            {
                int val = A[i];

                if (!tracker.ContainsKey(val))
                {
                    Dictionary<Indice, Indice> list = new Dictionary<Indice, Indice>();
                    Indice seed = new Indice(i, -1);
                    list.Add(seed, seed);
                    tracker.Add(val, list);
                }
                else
                {
                    Dictionary<Indice, Indice> list = tracker[val];

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<Indice,Indice> item in list.ToList())
                    {
                        Indice left = new Indice(item.Value.P, i);
                        Indice right = new Indice(i, item.Value.Q);

                        if (!list.ContainsKey(left))
                        {
                            list.Add(left, left);
                            Console.WriteLine("left= " + left);
                        }
                        if (!list.ContainsKey(right))
                        {
                            list.Add(right, right);
                            Console.WriteLine("\t\tright= " + right);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            return tracker.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).Count(num => num.Value.Q > num.Value.P);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ran tests and my solution died quick as Erick stated .. the solution irrelephant provided matched my results and then ran fine for much larger sets...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best version I got in c#.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new int[6] { 3, 5, 6, 3, 3, 5 };

        //Push the indices into an array:
        int[] indices = new int[a.Count()];
        for (int p = 0; p < a.Count(); ++p) indices[p] = p;

        //Sort the indices according to the value of the corresponding element in a:
        Array.Sort(indices, (k, l) =>Compare(a[k], a[l]));


        //Then just pull out blocks of indices with equal corresponding elements from indices:
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < indices.Count())
        {
            int start = i;
            while (i < indices.Count() && a[indices[i]] == a[indices[start]])
            {
                ++i;
            }
            int thisCount = i - start;

            int numPairs = thisCount * (thisCount - 1) / 2;

            count += numPairs;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    //Compare function to return interger
    private static int Compare(int v1, int v2)
    {
        if (v2 > v1)
            return 1;
        if (v1 == v2)
            return 0;
        else
            return -1;
    }
```

This approach has O(n log n) complexity overall, because of the sorting. The counting of the groups is linear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private static int GetIdenticalPairCount(int[] input)
    {
        int identicalPairCount = 0;
        Dictionary<int, int> identicalCountMap = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        foreach (int i in input)
        {
            if (identicalCountMap.ContainsKey(i))
            {
                identicalCountMap[i] = identicalCountMap[i] + 1;
                if (identicalCountMap[i] > 1)
                {
                    identicalPairCount += identicalCountMap[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    identicalPairCount++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                identicalCountMap.Add(i, 0);
            }
        }
        return identicalPairCount;
    }
```

Comment: Please add commentary as to how your code is different from the OPs, and what the specific improvements are.

Answer (score -3):

Test my version:

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{
    int N = A.Length;
    int count = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < N - 1; j++)
        for (int i = j + 1; i < N; i++)
            if (A[i] == A[j])
                count++;

    return count;
}
```

Comment: If something is wrong, please leave a comment. 
To everyone who voted down please if you have the courtesy to explain what is wrong.

Comment: Your solution is O(n^2). OP already has code of that complexity. He's looking for O(n log n).